# Log4j not printing logs to console on liberty Container

Tags: log4j, websphere-liberty

I am using log4j in web project war to print logs to file as well as console.

When in am running that war on my local liberty, it is working as expected.
When i am running that in liberty container, logs are going to file and not on console.
Attaching log4j and server.xml in zip.

Liberty version on local:
WebSphere Application Server Version 19.0.0.7 Liberty - (19.0.0.7-cl190720190711-1115)
OS: Windows
Java: IBM JDK 8

Liberty on container:
WebSphere Application Server 19.0.0.7/wlp-1.0.30.cl190720190711-1115
Image: registry.bluemix.net/ibm/liberty:webProfile8

[log4j and server.xml files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/17y6fnpPIHx2E93zb5JlBrddfQMxDx7Ry?usp=sharing)

Comment: So it's the exact same server.xml in both places? Same war as well? As opposed to like some local IDE publishing direct to Liberty? Can you shell into the container and look around at the configuration?

Comment: yes, i used same war and server.xml at both places. You want any specific from container configuration ?

Comment: No, I was just thinking if you could look around and see if everything looked the same. jvm.options, defaults, extension jars, etc.